# in typescript, how to define an object which method is generic function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

```
type T0<T> = {
    a: T
}

type T1<T> = {
    onStart(params: T0<T>, context: string): Promise<void>;
}


function onStart(params: { a: number }, context: string) {
    return Promise.resolve();
}

const t:T1 = {
    onStart: onStart
}
```

As above, when I want define onStart params type, it will tip error:

```
Type '(params: { a: number; }, context: string) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type '<T>(params: T0<T>, context: string) => Promise<void>'.
  Types of parameters 'params' and 'params' are incompatible.
    Type 'T0<T>' is not assignable to type '{ a: number; }'.
      Types of property 'a' are incompatible.
        Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2322)
input.tsx(6, 5): The expected type comes from property 'onStart' which is declared here on type 'T1'
```

playground url: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&e=181#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgDAHhgPigXigbwLACgoFQCGAXLHgL556iSwCM6WehUA9gHYDKwRATsCTIAFGH5EAtgGcy8IQBooAY07AIAD2BkpwPgEsOAcwCUZAAp82EvVIgIAbmz0ATZAG5K1XHgBmAVw4lYD1Odm5eAVFxaTJMYjIOPwkAIwg+KApFFQ41TW1dAxNmfEI+CGA-Pg4oCysbCAA6Mqk2ABt7CGFjD1wqb1xsnSgtGEYMHBKCTh5+LTCZgUogA

I think it is an common question: how to define an object which method is generic function in typescript?

Comment: The plain text code in your question exhibits a different error from the one mentioned.  Your playground link shows a different version of the code.  There is a difference between `type F<T> = (x: T)=>void` and `type F = <T>(x: T)=>void` and right now you're conflating them.  What are you *trying* to do, is it [this](https://tsplay.dev/NlEYGm)?  If so I could write up an answer, but either way you should explain clearly in the question what you want to accomplish and make sure your code is a [mre] of the issue you're facing.

Comment: Use the version from the post (not the version from the playground), but with `const t:T1<number>` instead